# systemd infinite loop with wall command

Tags: bash, centos, systemd, wall

I know this is a very unusual question but i had to create a bash script for a school project and I created a systemd service which calls a script on startup. Script contained (i think, cant check cause perma wall command) :

```
#!/bin/bash
until/while (ls /dev/pts/ | wc -l != 0) ## not sure if i added the != 0
do
   wall -n "this is a broadcast"
done
```

Is there a way to disable this script/wall command?

os is centOS stream 9 minimal installation (no gui) running in VirtualBox on MacOS

Comment: mount the virtualbox disk image on your host pc and remove or edit the systemd unit file.

Comment: @mashuptwice is this (including installing necessary commands to mount .vdi) possible without sudo? It's a school iMac.

Comment: The reason why I've added this as a comment in contrast to an answer is that I don't work with MacOS and therefore can't give you any qualified answers to MacOS. In case it doesn't work, you could spin up another linux VM and mount the image in there.

Comment: Thank you so much, will check it out tomorrow!

Comment: @GamingTurtle Since this is a VM, you could also try booting into rescue.target (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#rescue.target). You should then be able to troubleshoot from inside the VM, and not do anything on the host.

Comment: @Haxiel I tried entering rescue mode from grub boot menu but it was also affected by the service.

Comment: If you know how to blindly log in *and* know how you named the service (eg: myservice), you can just do this without looking at the screen: blindly log as root on console, and blindly type systemctl disable --now myservice

Comment: @mashuptwice mounting requires sudo although this would be a solution in this case it won't work.

Comment: @A.B wall command for some reason seems to affect both stdin and stdout, whenever I try to enter a command it will get mixed with the broadcast.

Comment: can't reproduce this here, but if you say so maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding the Virtual Disk Image as SATA device to a second linux VM, mounting it and commenting out the script.

Thanks everyone.